# RDP Connection closes due to Encryption error

Tags: rdp, encryption

My azure windows VM has been working fine for 3 months since it was set up.  I tried to reconnect today via RDP and it came up with  Remote Desktop Application - because of an error in data encrption this session will end.  It worked several times earlier today, but has been unable to connect for the past 3 hours.   I have tried connecting frmo another windows 10 PC and it comes up with the same error.

The health check on the azure VM management page has said it has had 3 errors today, but says it is working fine.

Is this a problem at the Azure server side, and if so, when will it be fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

It started working again after about 3 hours.  I assume it was an issue with the azure servers.  Hopefully it will be a long time until it happens again